# Customer Attributes in custom tab in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, customer-attribute

I'm trying to create a new attribute on customer but in backend, the attribute is getting saved under Account Information tab and I want it to be under a Custom Tab that I created (or create a new tab with attribute code id?). Here's what I have in my installer script

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getResource()
    ->getTypeId(); //customer entity type

$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId)
    ->setAttributeSetName("Marketing");

$attributeSet->validate();
$attributeSet->save();

$model =Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name',"Marketing")
    ->getFirstItem();

$modelGroup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group');
$modelGroup->setAttributeGroupName('Marketing Attributes');
$modelGroup->setAttributeSetId($model->getAttributeSetId());
$model->setGroups(array($modelGroup));
$model->save();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "my_new_attr", array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Dealer Info Updated",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => "No",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    "note"     => "To determine whether this Dealer's Info is updated"
));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "my_new_attr");

$attributeSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'Marketing');
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);
$installer->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'Marketing', 'my_new_attr', 10);
$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'my_new_attr', '101'  //sort_order
);


$used_in_forms = array();

$used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_edit";

$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
    ->setData("is_system", 0)
    //->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
    ->setData("is_visible", 0)
    //->setData("sort_order", 101)
;

// Save Attribute
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Is there a way to create this customer attribute under a custom tab?

**== UPDATE ==**
Here is a screenshot for better understanding of what I want to achieve... the custom attributes created from installer on customer, to be moved or installed in the custom tab:
[image: customer attribute]

Comment: Did you managed to do this ? I have to  do the same thing :)

Comment: try this link, may be it will help you.
http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information-in-magento-admin/

Comment: Have you completed this I also need this type of feature if  you have any idea please suggest